# both and also usage

Tags: grammar

If I want to describe that Jack has two roles in life, can I express like these:

Jack is both an engineer and a father.
Jack is an engineer and also a father.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Those two are never thought to be mutually exclusive, so the simple "Jack is an engineer and a father" is good enough. OTOH: "Jack is both a scientist and an artist" shows two sides of Jack that may be unexpected.

Answer (score -1):

Both options are fine. As Weather Vane says in a comment, using either of them suggests that it is somehow surprising or unexpected to find the two roles together: that might be what you intend, of course.